# Cyclical dependency - forward declaration not enough

Tags: c++, header, dependencies, header-files

Formatted code: http://pastie.org/5074835

I have a cyclical dependency between the Entity class and the Component class.
I tried forwarding the class declaration but I have to access Component's update method, and that way I can't.

Is there a way to make this work without redesigning?

Comment: You have to define the update- and init-method in Component.cpp

Comment: -1 For not providing the code in the question, and furthermore providing a link to an external site where the code is not the one causing the error.

Comment: Why would you prefer re-writing the code rather than copy-paste? WHY???

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I am sorry, I'm in a hurry to be honest. I'll make a more detailed question in a few hours. Sorry

Comment: @Vee: What you don't understand is that if the question is wrong you won't get the correct answers. Taking time to write the correct question (or at the very least the correct link) will actually make it *faster* for you to get the correct answer. Doing otherwise is wasting your time and the time of others. There's a saying in Spanish: *Vísteme despacio que tengo prisa*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas translation?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It's from very long ago, when people had servants that helped with everything: *Dress me slowly, I am in a hurry*.

Comment: Vee, for future reference, Stack Overflow typically generates *fast* response. You should be prepared to babysit your question for a while and make changes suggested in the comments immediately. Or you are likely to come in for some downvotes and/or a closure. (Even better would be writing a *good* question in the first place, of course, but if you are still learning that art being response is absolutely necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#include "Entity.h"` in `Component.cpp`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put it in the pastie. The include is there in my source code, and that file gives no problem. The problem is in Entity.cpp line 26, update() is not recognized

Comment: and the `#include <vector>` in Entity.cpp is not necessary

Comment: @Vee Copy-paste the code next time!!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in including `Entity.h` in `Component.cpp` and `Component.h` in `Entity.cpp`. A circular dependency will be if you include them in the header file. So go ahead and `#include "Entity.h" in`Component.cpp`.

Comment: The pastie is outdated, sorry. I tried doing that. The include is there in my source code, and that file gives no problem. The problem is in Entity.cpp line 26, update() is not recognized

Comment: +1 For the *no problem in including*, but there **is** a circular dependency whether the headers include each other or not. Dependencies are a design concept, header/implementation files are an implementation concept.

Comment: @Vee but you already use methods of `Component` in other methods of `Entity`, so `update()` should be recognized.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev push_back gives a similar problem, it says invalid template argument

Comment: @Vee then it should be something else, as you are including `Component.h`, so it must know what `Component` is. I see that you forward-declare `Component` in `Entity.cpp`, even though you do not need it (you already included its header). It shouldn't interfere but could you try removing it to see if the error goes away, just for reassuring.

Comment: @Vee I now see that actualy you do not need to `#include "Entity.h"` in `Component.cpp` as you do not call any methods of `Entity` there. So the forward declaration would do.

Answer (score 0):

Declare both classes with all methods, and define the metods afterwards?

header:

```
class B;

class A {
   void method1(B b);
};

class B {
   void method2(A a);
}
```

source file:

```
void A::method1(B b){
   ...
}

void B::method2(A a){
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is what he is already doing.